# CMD ¿Cómo obtengo la ip principal de un equipo si dispongo de varios adaptadores virtuales de red?

Tags: cmd, ip, networking

Trato de obtener la ip del equipo, en eso uso este comando de CMD y funciona.

`for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %a in ('ping -n 1 -4 "%computername%"') do @echo %a`

El Problema reside en que tengo varios adaptadores virtuales para maquinas virtuales y no se como "saltarme" esos para que llegue a la ip deseada que es la que tiene el sistema base, en este caso el wifi.
Pero que fuera valido para casos genéricos.
Sale algo asi:

```
Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Conexión de área local* 1:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Conexión de área local* 2:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

Adaptador de Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::d7f0:5a6b:bb53:ff7c%10
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.238.1
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . :

Adaptador de Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::ef80:62d:bd61:a839%20
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.64.1
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . :

Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Wi-Fi:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::4bf2:9495:fd5e:7b47%8
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.44
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Adaptador de Ethernet Conexión de red Bluetooth:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

Adaptador de Ethernet Ethernet:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
```

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como hacer eso?, Gracias.

Comment: Para ti ¿cuál es la IP principal?

Comment: En este caso el wifi, pero parte del problema es como identifico la que se usa como salida para navegar y no como una puerta para MV's.